# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError with Google Translate API in Python3

Tags: json, google-translation-api

Using regex I extract a substring from a Sentence and then translate it multiple times but sometimes I getting an error.

My code:

```py
from googletrans import Translator
try:
    translator = Translator()
    # substring Sentence:  Direccion  Referencia </tr> 
    # I want To Translate This Substring Sentence
    # Address = re.search(r'(?<=Direccion).*?(?=</tr>)' , 
              #new_get_htmlSource).group(0)
    # Address Substring From Website
    Address = re.search(r'(?<=<td>).*?(?=</td>)' , Address).group(0)
    translated = translator.translate(str(Address))
    Address = translated.text
except Exception as e :
     exc_type , exc_obj , exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
     fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
     print("Error ON : ",sys._getframe().f_code.co_name + "--> " + str(e) , 
     "\n" , exc_type , "\n" ,fname , "\n" , exc_tb.tb_lineno)
```

I expect the output of This: Reference  # Translated Text

I get this error:

```
scraping_data--> Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) 
 class: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError 
 Scraping_Things.py 
 29
```